# VBA Method for Indentation "Special Hanging"... spacing between bullet point and text

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically, I'm trying to find the VBA method that corresponds with the below since it seems to control the amount of distance between a bullet point its corresponding text ([image]):

[image]

Looking in the Object Browser for "hanging" these come up but don't seem to do what I am after:

[image]

`TabHangingIndent` just takes an integer as the parameter which is how many indents after the bullet point, not the actual distance when at default `TabHangingIndent(0)`.

`HangingPunctuation`... not sure what this does honestly, but it is a bool from what I can tell in the documentation. Looking for something that would likely need `InchesToPoints(x)`.

Any suggestions on the correct class and method to use?

Comment: Based on a quick recorded macro, try [`ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphformat.firstlineindent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just recording a macro to see what was being changed. Not the most intuitive thing:

```
With .Cell(r, c)
    .Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 153)
    .Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.1) 'was this line here
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0.1)
End With
```